# How to edit wp-config.php in openshift?

Tags: wordpress, openshift

I have my wordpress blog running over openshift server. I have added my own domain instead of opensift. But when i login it will show ssl error. I want to make it false in wp-config.php. But I don't know how to edit this file in openshift. Please help me.

Comment: i can't find wp-config using sftp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wp-config.php on openshift is located at $home/app-root/repo/php/wp-config.php (ie: /var/lib/openshift/xxxxUNIQUEAPPIDxxxx/app-root/repo/php/wp-config.php).

You can confirm that you are editing the right wp-config.php file by temporarily moving it to wp-config_copy.php and reloading your blog from a browser.  If you get a error that the wp-config.php is missing then you know you've got the right file. Move it back to wp-config.php.

Comment: thanks i have been edited these files using filezilla.

Answer (score 0):

use the FileZila for editing. may be it works. check if it shows any list of files.

Comment: it will show list of files but openshift structure is different.